# Dynamically assigning ID to an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a table cell with a dynamically assigned id like this,

```
    <tbody>
      {% for item in thread_model %}
      <tr>
       .....
        <td id="{{ item.id }}" class='btn vote_up'>{{ item.id }} Vote Up</td>
        <td id="{{ item.id }}" class='btn vote_down'>{{ item.id }} Vote Down</td>
        <td id="voted{{ item.id }}">{{ item.vote }}</td>
        ........
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

This works fine and then I have a bit of ajax which calls a Django view. But then I wish to set the innerHTML of that cell. But how do I get the jQuery to put the innerHTML into the table cell with the same id as the row of the vote up or down which I pressed?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.vote_up').on('click', function() {
    $.get("/vote_up/" + this.id + "/", function(data) {
      $('#voted' + this.id).innerHTML = data;
    });
  });
  $('.vote_down').on('click', function() {
    $.get("/vote_down/" + this.id + "/", function(data) {
      $('#voted' + this.id).innerHTML = data;
    });
  });
});
```

The urls,

```
url(r'^vote_up/(?P<id>\d+)/$', home.vote_up, name='vote_up'),
url(r'^vote_down/(?P<id>\d+)/$', home.vote_down, name='vote_down'),
```

The views look like this,

```
def vote_up(request, id):
    posts = PostModel.objects.get(pk = id)
    posts.vote += 1
    PostModel.objects.filter(pk=id).update(vote=posts.vote)
    return HttpResponse(posts.vote, content_type="text/plain")

def vote_down(request, id):
    posts = PostModel.objects.get(pk = id)
    posts.vote -= 1
    PostModel.objects.filter(pk=id).update(vote=posts.vote)
    return HttpResponse(posts.vote, content_type="text/plain")
```

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to include the `.vote_up`, `.vote_down` buttons in your answer. The problem is the ID's you assume you can use.

Comment: Of I need to correct teh question because it is id's that i am dealing with not classes.

Comment: For each row the cell has a different id. I want to grab that id again to populate the element's innerHTML with what I get back from the Django view. I will add the view too here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.id` is `undefind` inside `$.get`. SO you should change your code like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.vote_up').on('click', function() {
        var id = this.id;
        $.get("/vote_up/" + id + "/", function(data) {
          $('#voted' + id).html(data);
        });
      });
      $('.vote_down').on('click', function() {
        var id = this.id;
        $.get("/vote_down/" + id + "/", function(data) {
          $('#voted' + id).html(data);
        });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery `addClass()` method to assign classes dynamically to an element.

Example :

```
$("#ID").addClass("selected");
```

Or if you just want to add an style to and element you can use `css()` method

Example:

```
$("#ID").css( "color", "red" );
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: You can just as easily do this with pure JS, no?

Comment: With pure javascript we have to use .setAttribute method for doing it. Example :- document.getElementById("ID").setAttribute("class", "active");

Comment: Which is a lot faster (vanilla JS) and the length of API object and method names should tell you you should not query DOM more often than almost never. You should cache whenever there is a need to query a node twice or more. jQuery might've been good in the past but these days it is merely a cancer of web development. Encourages bad practices and is terribly slow.